# sequelize migrations relationship

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to learn Sequelize and tried to follow a few examples.
My problem now is that I am confused with the migrations in Sequelize.
When I create a new model with the CLI like this:

```
sequelize model:create --name Task --attributes title:string,content:string
```

It creates automatically a migration file for me.
If I then create another model "User" and add a relationship to the task model like this.

```
"use strict";
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    username: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
  classMethods: {
     associate: function(models) {
       // create one to many relationship
       User.hasMany(models.Task);
     }
  }
  });
  return User;
};
```

How can I write a migration for this relationship?

I found a post in the issues from 2013 where they say I have to do this manually but I don't really understand what that means. And I don't found a hint in the docs.

I found also a post where they say I should't use migrations and use the sync function with "force : true". But I don't like that this drops the table.